# Hiding scrollbars when OS sets always show scroll bars

Tags: html, css, macos, browser, scrollbar

I've noticed on Ubuntu and OSX (when an external mouse is used) that there is a settings to always show scrollbars on a page. When they are showing like this it makes our site look awful as the scrollbars do not agree with our colour scheme and they take up valuable space. The default setting on OSX of hiding scrollbars until you scroll works very well for us.

Is there any way we can disable or improve upon this in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is an OS-level setting that applies to every scrollable content window, not just web browsers.

> Is there any way we can disable or improve upon this in the browser?

I don't think so. If you're seeing scrollbars on elements *inside* your page (not just on the right side of window) then you may want to adjust your `overflow`/layout CSS on those elements.

Comment: But if I want these elements to be individually scrollable I'll have to just live with the scrollbars?